# Appveyor on_success script only run for commits to master

Tags: automation, git-flow, appveyor

Is is possible to make my appveyor on_success script only run for commits to master? and if so, how?

The following doesn't work (i.e. still runs the on_success script).

```
branches:
  only:
    - master
build: off
on_success:
- ps: write-host "test"
```

Comment: This should work. Common issues are: `Ignore appveyor.yml` setting, or wrong custom YAML file name, or generic `git` repository type (YAML file cannot be read from it). If your issues seems not from this list, you can send link to specific build which was run from different branch using this config, we can help more.

Comment: If I have the appveyor configuration specified; when I commit to a non-master branch e.g. "test", appveyor will still do a build against master.

If I have the following line in my on_success script:
    Write-Host "Branch is '$env:APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH'"

Then "Branch is 'master'" is displayed in the appveyor build console.

Basically, I want commits to non-master branches to be totally skipped...

Comment: Please send a link to specific build which started against `master` after commit to `test` Is it pull request by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Environment Variable](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/environment-variables/) within the PowerShell script and a simple `if` statement. The `APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH` environment variable should be what you are looking for.

You can access these variables in PowerShell like `$env:APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH`, or in `cmd` like `%APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH%`

`on_success` should now look like:

```
on_success:
- ps: if ($env:APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH -eq "master") {Write-Host "master branch"}
```